# RSPEC bug with a class Parser (?)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I think I hit a bug in RSPEC bug, while just trying it for the first time...

In the following example, **RSPEC is sensitive to the name of the class** : with '**Parser**' in parser.rb file the test fails, but just renaming it 'FooParser' makes it work.

```
require_relative './parser.rb'
describe Parser do
    it 'should do the trick' do
       @parser = Parser.new "test.pas"
    end
end
```

will complain about my constructor argument, even having a plain code like this :

```
class Parser 
  def initialize arg
  end
end
```

The RSPEC erroneous log looks like this :

```
1) Parser should do the trick
    Failure/Error: @parser = Parser.new "test.pas"
       ArgumentError:
        wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

Comment: Give us a stack trace and the exact error message or it didn't happen.

Comment: This isn't the place to ask if a RSpec bug has been reported.

Answer (score 0):

The spec as written in your question should work (and accomplish nothing, by the way), but I'm guessing that in your real spec you tried to use `should` with an implicit subject, like this:

```
it 'should do the trick' do
   @parser = Parser.new "test.pas"
   should_not be_nil
end
```

If you use `should` or `should_not` bare like this, Rspec has to figure out what you're testing. It'll see if you are describing a class -- which you are -- and will try to instantiate it -- in your case using `Parser.new` with no arguments.

You may have wanted something like this:

```
it 'should do the trick' do
   Parser.new("test.pas").should_not be_nil
end
```

This is a dumb test, but maybe it illustrates (what could be) the problem.